# Which interface controls 'Place overlapping labels' for a feature layer?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects

I need to turn on the option to 'Place overlapping labels' for a feature layer via ArcObjects. In the ArcMap UI it is located here:

[image]

I can get to most of the labeling options from the IAnnotateLayerProperties, ILabelEngineLayerProperties and IBasicOverposterLayerProperties interfaces.

The option to control overlapping labels seems to be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following VBA code demonstrates how to turn that property on:

```vb
Public Sub test()
    ' Get document
    Dim pMXDocument As IMxDocument
    Set pMXDocument = ThisDocument

    ' Get map
    Dim pMap As IMap
    Set pMap = pMXDocument.FocusMap

    ' Get first layer, assumed this is what you want to label
    Dim pLayer As ILayer
    Set pLayer = pMap.Layer(0)
    Dim pGeoFeatureLayer As IGeoFeatureLayer
    Set pGeoFeatureLayer = pLayer

    ' Ensure labels are visible
    pGeoFeatureLayer.DisplayAnnotation = True

    ' Get Annotation properties collection
    Dim pAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection As IAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection2
    Set pAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection = pGeoFeatureLayer.AnnotationProperties

    ' Get the annotation layer property
    Dim pAnnotateLayerProperties As IAnnotateLayerProperties
    Dim id As Long
    pAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection.QueryItem 0, pAnnotateLayerProperties, id

    ' Get label engine, do this by QI annotation layer property
    Dim pLabelEngineLayerProperties As ILabelEngineLayerProperties2
    Set pLabelEngineLayerProperties = pAnnotateLayerProperties

     ' Set overposter properties
    Dim pBasicOverposterLayerProperties As IBasicOverposterLayerProperties4
    Set pBasicOverposterLayerProperties = pLabelEngineLayerProperties.BasicOverposterLayerProperties
    pBasicOverposterLayerProperties.GenerateUnplacedLabels = True
    Dim pOverposterLayerProperties As IOverposterLayerProperties2
    Set pOverposterLayerProperties = pLabelEngineLayerProperties.OverposterLayerProperties
    pOverposterLayerProperties.TagUnplaced = False

    ' Refresh display
    pMXDocument.ActiveView.Refresh
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Hornbydd for the accepted answer. Below is the solution in C# in case it helps anyone. The method call to get to the label engine properties is slightly different than vba.

```
IGeoFeatureLayer geoFeatureLayer = (IGeoFeatureLayer)featureLayer;
geoFeatureLayer.DisplayAnnotation = true;

IAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection propertiesColl = geoFeatureLayer.AnnotationProperties;
IAnnotateLayerProperties labelEngineProperties = new LabelEngineLayerProperties() as IAnnotateLayerProperties;
IElementCollection placedElements = new ElementCollectionClass();
IElementCollection unplacedElements = new ElementCollectionClass();
propertiesColl.QueryItem(0, out labelEngineProperties, out placedElements, out unplacedElements);

ILabelEngineLayerProperties labelEngineLayerProperties = labelEngineProperties as ILabelEngineLayerProperties;
labelEngineProperties.AnnotationMinimumScale = 2500000;
labelEngineProperties.Priority = 0;

IBasicOverposterLayerProperties4 basicOverposterLayerProperties =
    (IBasicOverposterLayerProperties4)labelEngineLayerProperties.BasicOverposterLayerProperties;
basicOverposterLayerProperties.LabelWeight = esriBasicOverposterWeight.esriHighWeight;

IOverposterLayerProperties2 overposterLayerProperties2 =
    (IOverposterLayerProperties2)basicOverposterLayerProperties;
overposterLayerProperties2.TagUnplaced = false;

ArcMap.Document.ActiveView.Refresh();
ArcMap.Document.CurrentContentsView.Refresh(null);
```