# Enabling "Place Overlapping labels" in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, labeling

I am currently using ArcObjects and I'm trying to tick the "Place Overlapping labels" option programatically.

I have been using Standard `ILabelEngineProperties` and the properties of `BasicOverposterLayerProperties`.

I just cannot find this particular option

Comment: You need to use the IOverposterLayerProperties2 interface and set TagUnplaced = false.  I believe this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Ok, so It worked. You should add this to answers so I can upvote you. Thank you very much !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which interface controls 'Place overlapping labels' for a feature layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190597/which-interface-controls-place-overlapping-labels-for-a-feature-layer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [IOverposterLayerProperties2](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IOverposterLayerProperties2_TagUnplaced.htm) interface and set TagUnplaced = false